# Polymorphic type inside a module (OCaml)

Tags: types, module, polymorphism, ocaml

I just define a Matrix module as follows:

```
module Matrix =
  struct
    type element
    type t = element array array

    let make (nr: int) (nc: int) (init: element) : t =
      let result = Array.make nr (Array.make nc init) in
      for i = 0 to nr - 1 do
        result.(i) <- Array.make nc init
      done;
      result
  end
```

And `let m = Matrix.make 3 4 0` gives me an error `Error: This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type Matrix.element`. Then I added `'a`:

```
module Matrix =
  struct
    type element = 'a
    type t = element array array

    let make (nr: int) (nc: int) (init: element) : t =
      let result = Array.make nr (Array.make nc init) in
      for i = 0 to nr - 1 do
        result.(i) <- Array.make nc init
      done;
      result
  end
```

The compilation of the module gives an error `Error: Unbound type parameter 'a`.

Could anyone tell me how to define the type inside of my module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two problems: (1) type variables cannot be named by a binding, like you tried with `element`, and (2) your type `t` needs to have all type variables as parameters if it is supposed to be polymorphic. That is, you either want to write

```
type 'a t = 'a array array
```

or you have to turn the module into a functor, where you take `element` as a parameter of the entire module.

Comment: I have a question, is it possible to do : `module Element =
struct
  type 'a t = 'a 
  let compare = compare
end;; module ElementMap = Map.Make(Element)` ? I get "Error: Signature mismatch:"

Comment: That's not possible, because Map.Make expects a parameter-less type t. You would need a different version of Map to make that possible.